# How to retrieve all event informations about events for a specific room in microsoft outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, mendix

I am building an app which lets users book a room and create an event in their calendar and the rooms calendar. I am trying to retrieve event information of scheduled events for specific rooms in our outlook room list with microsoft graph api so that I can display already booked events. I've tried using (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendar/getSchedule) and including the room email in the request body like this:

```
{
    "schedules": [
        "room@email"
    ],
    "startTime": {
        "dateTime": "2021-09-12",
        "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "dateTime": "2021-11-13",
        "timeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
    },
    "availabilityViewInterval": 15
}
```

This gives me the scheduled items but they're not complete. For example the organizer is missing, the attendees are missing, and sometimes the locaiton.

Is it possible to retrieve **all** information or is this the best that it gets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getSchedule queries the FreeBusy information for a Mailbox and the level of detail you get back from that depends on the security setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/calendars/users-can-see-only-basic-freebusy-mailbox-information and Calendar polices that are set on each Mailbox eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/client-connectivity/calendar-shows-organizer-name etc

If you query the events endpoint of the Mailbox in question you will get all the information that is available but for some properties in Room mailbox especially depending on the calendar setting you won't see everything.